# Linking QML to C++ - or should I?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm creating my first program with Qt (as was recommended by SO members in an earlier question). In its documentation, the Qt community encourages the use of QML as a markup language and JavaScript to handle logic. Sounds promising, but the docs lack a good beginner's explanation of how and when those two would tie in with C++.

From the [Qt 5 docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html):

> While it is possible to use C++ to access and manipulate QML objects
>   deep into the object tree, we recommend that you do not take this
>   approach outside of application testing and prototyping.

Say we have a `QtQuick2ApplicationViewer` object as our main view, as generated by the default Qt Creator template. At first, I'd like to show a welcome screen for which I've created `welcome.qml`. When the user clicks a button, the main program runs, i.e. `app.qml`. From what I've gathered my `main` function should thus look like this:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QtQuick2ApplicationViewer view; // Class generated by the default template.
view.setSource(QUrl("welcome.qml")); // Load QML.
view.showExpanded();

return app.exec();
```

Works like a charm. According to the docs I should now have a `welcome.js` file that handles closing the welcome screen. Now I'm confused though - how will the JavaScript communicate back to the `view` that `app.qml` is to be loaded? More importantly: should it?

Comment: You have to import the JavaScript file in your QML. Then in one of your QML controls or areas you have to bind the JavaScript function to that control's signal (`onClicked` for example).

Comment: @W.B. thanks - I'm wondering though, does this mean I should write most of the app's logic in JS?

Comment: I linked to the same summary in my question :).

Comment: No, see the other comment I've made. You don't have to use JavaScript at all, if you don't wish to. You can connect to your QML components' signals straight from C++. But using JS can be much quicker in certain situations. And sorry for the same link :). Deleted the comment.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought... I felt like I was doing things wrong by disregarding C++, but the docs kept steering me away from integrating QML with C++. Thanks for clearing it up @W.B.

Comment: Actually, that's not the impression I had when reading that. I think the approach they recommend is to expose your app's logic to QML and have QML invoke some of those functions. For instance, you expose some `cleanUp` functionality to QML. Then on clicking the close button, you invoke your app's `cleanUp` from QML and then close the window. Same with other stuff. You expose, say, `addCustomer`, then from QML you gather all user input and invoke `addCustomer` with new customer's data. That's what I think the recommended approach is to integrating QML and C++ - no knowledge of QML on C++ side.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, but where should I draw the line between JS and C++ functionality? For example, Qt's 'advanced QML tutorial' is a QML/JS game that even uses JS to save a high score to a SQL database: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-tutorials-samegame-samegame4-example.html

Comment: There's no set line. You can say you want to use JS for UI only, or you can use it for app's logic, because that's faster. It's up to you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Robbert,

If I am correct, you want to know how to navigate from one screen to another. Example: from  *welcome.qml* to *app.qml*.

Now coming to your question...
 *how will the JavaScript communicate back to the view that app.qml is to be loaded? More importantly: should it?*

From QML side, you can communicate with the C++ native side and make '*view*' load *app.qml*. Perfectly possible.

*More importantly: should it?* : Not necessary. You can load different qml files without communicating '*view*' You need to tweak your code a bit. Instead of doing this..

```
 view.setSource(QUrl("welcome.qml"));
```

You must do this..

```
view.setSource(QUrl("main.qml"));
```

Here *main.qml* is a qml file responsible for loading different qml files. To start with, it will load '*welcome.qml*' You need to use [QML Loader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) in your main.qml for loading different qml files.

The idea is to have *welcome.qml * emit a signal, say showAppPage() on receiving which *main.qml* will load *app.qml*. The following is a  simple example which does the same.

```
//Main.qml
import QtQuick 2.1
Item {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Loader{
        id:pageLoader
        source: "welcome.qml"
    }
    Connections{
        target: pageLoader.item
        onShowAppPage:{
            pageLoader.source = "app.qml"
        }
    }
}
```

Welcome page

```
//welcome.qml
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color:"blue"
    signal showAppPage;
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: showAppPage()
    }
}
```

App page

```
//app.qml
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color:"red"
}
```

You can also load welcome.qml and app.qml from main.qml without using Loader and using Qt.createComponent method. But QML Loader serves the purpose in your case. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for answering in such detail. The Loader type was the missing piece of the puzzle. Marking this as Best Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the location of the line depends on where you draw it :) Most applications can be divided into a core models, some viewmodels, and some views. The viewmodels adapt the model's data for display/editing.

If you were to implement a QWidget-based GUI for your application, you might find that some viewmodel functionality could be shared between the Qt Quick 2 GUI and the Qt Widgets GUI. This *does not* mean that viewmodel implementation needs to be in C++, not at all.

QML is completely GUI-agnostic. You can code in QML and still use QWidgets to actually show stuff. Note that Qt Quick 2 is just a set of components that you can use from QML, but QML itself is an underlying platform that doesn't know anything about GUIs at all. It can be used in a text-only or even server-only application

If you factor some viewmodel functionality out into GUI-agnostic QML, you can certainly hook it up from both Qt Quick 2 and Qt Widgets - even if it's done in Javascript.

Comment: Thank you Kuba, very helpful! I guess I'll find out along the way where I want to draw the line then. So far I like being able to code most of the app in JS.